# CakePHP select option class

Tags: php, class, cakephp, select

Does someone know how to add class to a select option in a view file ?

I have at the moment:

```
echo $this->Form->input(
                'shelf_id',
                array(
                    'options' => $Shelves,
                    'label'=> 'Etagère :',
                    'default' => $Place['Place']['shelf_id'],
                    'class'=>'form-control')
            );
```

All my options element are like this :

```
<option value="1">Element</option>
```

But I want them to be like this :

```
<option value="1" class="myClass">Etagere 1</option>
```

The value of the option class should be the id of each shelve, but what I have now is :

```
<select>
<option class="1" value="1">Etagere 1</option>
<option class="1" value="2">Etagere 2</option>
<option class="1" value="3">Etagere 3</option>
<option class="1" value="4">Etagere 4</option>
<option class="1" value="5">Etagere 5</option>
<option class="1" value="6">Etagere 6</option>
</select>
```

But I want the class="..." with the id of each shelve id.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe Cake provides a simple way of adding a class to the individual `<option>` tags.

What you can do is build the options yourself using `Html::tag()` remembering to take into account the `selected` option. For example, you could do something a little like the following:-

```
<select>
<?php
    // Work out what the selected value is (falling back on a default)
    $selected = !empty($this->request->data['Place']['shelf_id']) ? $this->request->data['Place']['shelf_id'] : $Place['Place']['shelf_id'];
    // Generate the <option> tags
    foreach ($Shelves as $key => $val) {
        echo $this->Html->tag(
            'option', 
            $val, 
            array(
                'class' => 'myClass',
                'value' => $key
                'selected' => $selected === $key ? 'selected' : null
            )
        )
    }
?>
</select>
```

You would need to put the correct attributes on the `<select>` tag and add the label to this. You should be able to see what these are by looking at the markup produced by the code in your question.

**Update**

For the `<option>` tag class to be the same as its value just pass the `$key` to the `class` attribute:-

```
foreach ($Shelves as $key => $val) {
    echo $this->Html->tag(
        'option', 
        $val, 
        array(
            'class' => $key,
            'value' => $key
            'selected' => $selected === $key ? 'selected' : null
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that a beginning ! I have to find how to print <option value="1" class="$Place['Place']['shelf_id']">Etagere 1</option> for each shelve, because at the moment, it prints the same id.

Comment: @Raphael I'm not clear what you mean by printing the same `id`. Is your `$Shelves` array in the correct format of `primaryKey => displayField`?

Comment: I had edit my question. Currently, I have the shelf id of the selected shelf, but I want the shelf id for each one.

Comment: @Raphael you just need to pass the `$key` to the `class` attribute. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

create your `$Shelves` array like this

```
$Shelves =  array(
    array('value' => 1, 'name' => 'first option', 'class' => 1),
    array('value' => 2, 'name' => 'second option', 'class' => 2),
    array('value' => 3, 'name' => 'third option', 'class' => 3)
);
```

see this [link](http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/03/01/some-new-crazy-cakephp-tricks/)

Answer (score 0):

The method 'arilia' is referring to seems to no longer work. I had a prepared an array as described but instead of the class attribute being populated, the value was a concatenation of all the array values, that was using this method:

```
echo $this->Form->input('input_id', ['options' => $inputArray, 'empty' => true]);
```

Instead I generated the HTML manually:

```
echo '<label for="input-id">Input</label>';
echo '<select id="input-id" name="input_id" required="required">';
echo '<option value="" data-attribute=""> </option>';

foreach($inputArray as $inputRow){
    echo '<option value="'.$inputRow['value'].'" data-attribute="'.$inputRow['data-attribute'].'">'.$inputRow['data'].'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
```